# Unicode case conversion

Tags: python, unicode, case-sensitive

I am given either a single character or a string, and am using Python.

How do I find out if a specific character has a lowercase equivalent according to the standards (standard and special case mappings) proposed by Unicode?

And how do I find out if a string has one or more characters that have a lowercase equivalent according to the standards (standard and special case mappings) proposed by Unicode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def haslower(unicodechar):
    return unicodechar != unicodechar.lower()

def anylower(unicodestring):
    return any(haslower(c) for c in unicodestring)
```

This will only work correctly in as much as the Python version you're using has correctly implemented the `.lower()` method per unicode standards, of course.  Also, I'm assuming that you don't consider, e.g., `u'a'`, to "have a lowercase equivalent" (it has an *uppercase* one of course).  If you mean something different, consider

```
def changescase(uc):
    return uc != uc.lower() or uc != uc.upper()
```

(I've renamed the argument to `uc` to avoid excessive line length;-) -- if that's what you want I recommend *not* naming the function in terms of "lowercase equivalent" as that would be sure to confuse readers/maintainers of your code!-)

Comment: It never occurred to me that .lower (and .upper) would work for accented characters too.

Comment: Thanks. I run my app in GAE, so it's Python 2.5.2. I asked another question, just in case you'd like to answer it (for others to also see). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536397/does-python-version-2-5-2-follow-unicode-standards-for-lower-and-upper-functi

Answer (score 1):

@Albert, You appear to be overly concerned with the minutiae of case conversion, when you haven't yet sorted out (nor explained to answerers) what you really want to do.

=== Your previous attempt at explanation (in comment on my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508490/python-how-to-check-if-a-unicode-string-contains-a-cased-character/3510087#3510087)) ===

@John: Well, I'm actually making an API for my web service. My webservice accepts a key that maps out to a specific record in my database. The key is case-sensitive, and the key can be composed of any unicode characteer. So in order to normalize all input, I will convert all key queries into lowercase (if they have uppercase equivalents). A consequence of that is when I create the record keys (which my users can customize), **I cannot accept any uppercase character that can be converted to a lowercase equivalent by the toLower() function. So I'm trying to make a filter for that. Any suggestions?**

=== and my replying comment ===

@Albert: If your keys are case sensitive, why are you normalising them??? "record keys which users can customize" means what??? "any unicode char" vs "cannot accept any uppercase char" ??? **To answer your question literally: Looks like you can't accept a character c when c.lower() != c which means that you can't accept any key if key.lower() != key.** I think that you should start a NEW QUESTION, explaining exactly what you are trying to do, with examples.

... and you've certainly asked a new question (in fact 2 of them) but you haven't explained anything. This "new" question is so new that @Alex Martelli's answer is essentially the same as my comment highlighted above.

I think that you should start a NEW QUESTION, **with new content**, explaining exactly what you are trying to do, with examples.

Comment: Alright. I'll put together what I exactly am trying to do. Thanks!