# Does Python 2.5.2 follow Unicode for lower() and upper()?

Tags: python, unicode, case-sensitive

I'm making a Google AppEngine Application. Does the Python 2.5.2 runtime environment follow the Unicode Standards? (For example, the lower() and upper() methods on unicode objects.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes and no.

For an example, see the code being discussed here: [How can I convert Unicode to uppercase to print it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727507/how-can-i-do-unicode-uppercase-in-python)

Check here for a formal, well-written document:

http://www.cmlenz.net/archives/2008/07/the-truth-about-unicode-in-python